# How to dynamically insert strings in my linked list?

Tags: c, list, data-structures

My C program should read an input file and save it line for line in a linked list, then printing it. But when it's inserting the next line in the list, all elements in the list become the new element.

Input:

abc
def
ghi

Output:

ghi
ghi
ghi

I'm not sure but my guess is that it's not correctly allocating new memory for new elements in the list.

This is the code:

```
#include "listd.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void show(Value v) {
    printf(v);
    printf("\n");
}

int main( void ) {
    List lines = init();
    char a;
    while(a != EOF){
        a=getchar();
        char currentline[256] = " ";
        int i = 0;
        while(a != '\n' && a != EOF){
            currentline[i]=a;
            a = getchar();
            i++;
        }
        lines = insert(currentline, lines); //Here is probably the error
    }
    iterate(lines, show);
}
```

listd.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEFAULT 0

typedef enum {False ,True} Bool;
typedef char* Value;
typedef void (*VProc)(Value);
typedef struct _list {
    Value val;
    struct _list *next;
} Elem , *List;

List init() { return NULL; }
List insert(Value v, List l) {
    List e = malloc( sizeof (Elem));
    e->val = v;
    e->next = l;
    return e ;
}
void iterate(List l, VProc p) {
    for (;!empty(l);l=tail(l)) p(head(l));
    }
```

listd.h was given to us. But it was made for int, so I changed

```
typedef int Value;
```

to

```
typedef char* Value;
```

Comment: All data members val of nodes point to the same local array aktzeile. So what you do is what you get. You should dynamically allocate character arrays for data member val and copy strings into them.

Comment: You're going to have to duplicate that string or you're stomping the same memory location with each line. `strdup()` or `strncpy()` into a new buffer.

Comment: @Ben  Take into account that this code snippet     char a;
    while(a != EOF){ invokes undefined behavior because the variable a is not initialized and has indeterminate value.

Comment: @Vlad Yes, you are right. When I change aktzeile I change the output. Thanks for your help, I see if I can solve the problem now.

Comment: @Ben, just a tip, while not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It's style, so it up to you, but when you fail to follow it, it says a lot about your code before you even get to the details `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue1:** In struct _list, val is a char pointer.
When you do malloc( sizeof (Elem)), only memory for the two pointers(char*, struct_list*) is allocated.

**Issue2:** When  e->val = v is executed it copies the char* v to e->val. It does not copy the string but only pointer. Here v is currentline. So it is obvious that e->val for all the elements will be the pointer to the last value which is stored in currentline. In this case, the last value is "ghi".

Please try below code and let me know:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DEFAULT 0

typedef enum {False ,True} Bool;
typedef char* Value;
typedef void (*VProc)(Value);
typedef struct _list {
    Value val;
    struct _list *next;
} Elem , *List;

List init() { return NULL; }
List insert(Value v, List l) {
    List e = malloc( sizeof (Elem));
    e->val = malloc(strlen(v) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(e->val, v);
    e->next = l;
    return e ;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked out fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You program is having **undefined behavior** as you are accessing address of local variable outside of its scope.

The scope of `currentline` is within the while loop - `while(a != EOF)` as it has been declared inside the loop block.

In `insert()`, you are doing:

```
e->val = v;
```

The **`val` pointer (type `char *`) of each element of list `lines` is pointing to `currentline` and `currentline` does not exist out of `while` loop block**. Your program accessing the list `lines` outside the `while` loop block as well which is leading to undefined behavior.

From [C Standards:](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2)

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address,33) and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.34) If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

An [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) includes - program may work as expected or it may crash or anything can happen. As the `val` pointer of all the elements of the list is pointing to the same memory location which is `currentline`, the last value of `currentline` is the value you are getting when you are printing the value pointer `val` of all elements of list `lines` pointing to. You are lucky that you are not getting any error while your program is accessing object memory outside of its scope. But this may not be the case every time when you run your program.

To fix this problem, you should allocate memory to `val` pointer and copy the value `currentline` to it.

You can do:

```
List insert(Value v, List l) {
    List e = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    if (NULL == e)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    e->val = malloc((strlen(v)+1) * sizeof(char));
    if (NULL == e->val)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    strcpy(e->val, v);
    e->next = l;
    return e ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. This is a hard topic for me and this helps me to get the hang of it.